# An expression, almost facetious, similar to "I offer you my emotional support" i.e. in lieu on money!

Tags: colloquialisms

I ask for money to start a business and some say, "we'll give you our ____ support" in a funny way. Drawing a blank on this old, familiar expression! Like "you have my emotional, or thoughtful or *something* support" ???

Comment: How about "thoughts and prayers"?

Answer (score 2):

***Moral support***

> If you give someone moral support, you encourage that person and show that you approve of what they are doing, rather than giving practical help.

[-Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/moral-support)

We will give you our *moral support.*